# Discriminate union types

Tags: typescript, types, discriminated-union

Why i cannot discriminate that union with just the information that the member x is a string and not a number ? Why do i have to use a literal type ?

```
type A = { x: string ; y: string }
type B = { x: number ; y: number }
type C = A | B

function fn(p: C) {
  if (typeof p.x === 'string') { 
    // Typescript is unable to infer p as A
    // Typescript infer p.y as (string | number), why not just string ?
  }
  // Typescript is capable of inferring p.x as number - good
  // But cannot infer p.y as number, why ?
}
```

For me this is not possible to call the function with a type like this {x:string,y:number}, so why typescript assume this is possible ?

Comment: This code is not logical, `typeof { x: string ; y: string }` would be object, never string

Comment: I edit the post, sorry

Answer (score 4):

Not directly an explanation why the Typescript compiler cannot distinguish a union type by `typeof`, but the [handbooks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) says:

> There are three ingredients:
>
> 1. Types that have a common, ***singleton type*** property — the discriminant.
> 2. A type alias that takes the union of those types — the union.
> 3. Type guards on the common property.

So for narrowing down the correct type a *singleton type* property is necessary. I would use custom type guards:

```ts
type A = { x: string ; y: string }
type B = { x: number ; y: number }
type C = A | B

function isA(obj: C): obj is A { 
  return typeof obj.x === 'string';
}

function isB(obj: C): obj is B { 
  return typeof obj.x === 'number';
}

function fn(p: C) {

  if (isA(p)) {
    // ...
  }

  if (isB(p)) {
    // ...
  }

}
```

Comment: It seems like it should be like that `function isB(obj: C): obj is B`

Answer (score 2):

If you can express type in classes, then I recommend doing so:

```
class A { x: string; y: string; }
class B { x: number; y: number }
type C = A | B
function fn(p: C) {
    if (p instanceof A) {
        // { x: string; y: string; }
    }
    if (p instanceof B) {
        // { x: number; y: number }
    }

}
```

In this case, you can use [instanceof](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#instanceof-type-guards) magic. This is the best way. Otherwise, you need to check all property because the [keyword type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases) adds only definitions to the source.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative, but i would like to understand why typescript is not capable to correctly infer types in my example.

Comment: @Romain Because `typeof` works like that and after typeof value should be cast to the desired type

Comment: typeof allow Typescript to infer p.x with no cast, in the case this is a number or a string. But typescript stop there, whereas it have all the information to infer p.y too

Answer (score 0):

Though this question was asked for more than one year ago. I hope that my **demonstration** can help someone who found this question.

*The following explanation is quoted from "Programming Typescript" with some modification to fit the sample code here:*

> When `isAorB` takes a parameter of type "AorB", that doesn't mean we have to pass a `A` or a `B` -- in fact, we could pass an argument of type `A | B`

```
type A = { x: string ; y: string };
type B = { x: number; y: number };
type AorB = A | B;

const c = { x: "str", y: "str" };

function isAorB(p: AorB) {
    if (typeof p.x === "number") { 
        const alsoCx = p.x; // number
        const alsoCy = p.y; // string | number
        return;
    }
    const alsoCx = p.x; // string
    const alsoCy = p.y; // string | number
}

isAorB(c);
```

I do admit I still don't understand the logic after staring the paragraph for a long time.

However, I tried a lot of combinations of types and think Typescript assumes the following is also a possible input:

```
// The above c really satisfy type C here.
type C = { x: string | number ; y: string | number };
```

Although it might even not be an answer without knowing how Typescript parse the above logic. Now the above behavior looks not so strange to me.

*Note: if you define `c` as `const c: C = ...`, you will actually encounter an error when calling `isAorB(c)`*

Since you mention "literal type", I assume that you know a simple solution is to add a "unique literal" value in all the common key of the union object to distinguish them.
Here is a short sample for those who don't know (since no one yet post a sample with this kind of solution).

**Use Unique [Literal Tag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) to Solve Ambiguous:**

```
// Notice "z" satisfy the condition of being a unique literal.
type A = { z: "A", x: string ; y: string }; 
type B = { z: "B", x: number; y: number };
type AorB = A | B;

function isAorB(p: AorB ) {
    if (p.z === "A") { 
        const onlyAx = p.x; // string
        const onlyAy = p.y; // string
        return;
    }
    const onlyBx = p.x; // number
    const onlyBy = p.y; // number
}
```

Notice that `c` with the following form will lead to an error when call `isAorB(c)` now.

```
const c = { x: "str", y: "str", z: "A" };
```

and you can do something like this to ensure the `z`

```
const c = { x: "str", y: "str", z: "A" as "A" };
```