# typescript error dealing with a union type

Tags: typescript, casting

I have the below function taking a parameter of one of three types as an argument. Using type comparison, I am picking the correct response shape as below.

```
const buildAddress = (
  address: VerifiedStandardAddress | VerifiedExtendedAddress | Address
): Record<string, unknown> => {
  if (typeof address !== Address.name) {
    return {
      city: address.city,
      line1: address.address_line_1,
      line2: address.address_line_2,
      last_line: address.address_last_line,
      postal_code: address.postal,
      postal_ext: address.postal_ext,
      state: address.region
    }
  }

  return {
    city: address.city,
    line1: address.line1,
    line2: address.line2,
    postal_code: address.postal_code,
    state: address.state
  }
}
```

However, the typescript compiler complains that, for example, `Property 'state' does not exist on type 'VerifiedExtendedAddress'`. It is correct. This property exists on on type `Address`.

Is there a way to avoid this, short of splitting this code into two functions?

Comment: `typeof address !== Address.name` looks like a bug FYI.

Comment: To be more specific, that's the *runtime Javascript* `typeof` operator, and it's just going [to return "object"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), not your actual type. Typescript has type erasure, they "compile away" so they don't exist at runtime.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discriminate union types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59840445/discriminate-union-types)